# Iterating through range[]

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, callback

I'm trying to do two things. Get this to work, and get it to work as efficient as possible.

The task:

To take a user defined RANGE like the following:

[image: My Spreadsheet]

What I want to do is simply run a foreach loop that will go through the selection and pull out specific cells then place them into a copy of a template document

```
var ranger = sheet.getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges().forEach(function(dataArray) 
  // dataArray is my object[][] Casting all data to strings just in case.
  var songname = String(dataArray[1]);
  var songwriters = String(dataArray[2]);
  var publishers =  String(dataArray[3]);
  var artist = String(dataArray[5]);
  var useremail = String(dataArray[6]);
...
}
```

Later in my code, I open the template, replace the placeholders, rename and save it.

But I just want to get there, and get there **as efficiently as possible.**

Is this going to do it?

I'm very confused by the callback formatting in Google App Scripting.

Comment: forEach return value is undefined according to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach  so ranger with always be undefined.

Comment: I think that there is the syntax error in `forEach` in your script. And, although `dataArray` is the Range object, `dataArray` is used like `var songname = String(dataArray[1]);`. I think that in this case, `undefined` is returned. From these situation, I cannot understand about your current situation and goal. So in order to correctly understand about your question, can I ask you about the detail of your current situation and goal? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: dataArray is not a data Array it's a range.  If you want a data array then you need to take a range and use a method like getValues() and then you will have a data array.  You should page more attention to each methods return values in the documentation

Comment: I think that the question requires more focus more specifically, first focus on getting a code that works, then you could focus on optimize it. By the other hand, if you are looking for help to debug code you should include an [mcve].

Comment: My goal is to go through the selection Row by Row, picking the cells I need. I want to do this in the most efficient way possible. I know dataArray is a misnomer, but that I can move beyond this nominal confusion quickly.

Answer (score 2):

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var dataArray=[];
  sh.getSelection().getActiveRangeList().getRanges().forEach(function(r,i){
    dataArray.push(r.getValues());
  }); 
  ....
```

dataArray is now and array of 2 dimensional arrays so it's a 3 dimensional array.

Comment: I'm confused by your 2D vs. 3D verbiage.

But I see what you are doing here. You are first creating an empty array, then pushing the row values into it. Is this optimal? In terms of resources?

Comment: [Class Range Method getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) returns a 2 dimensional array.

Comment: I'm going to post a new question that I think is more specific and to the point. Thank you all for the comments and questions